# Getting error when navigate to another page

Tags: jquery, html, listview, navigation, collapsable

I'm developing a web application which contains the collapsible listview. When I click on the       `<li>` the current page ( `#biblepage`) has to navigate to another page ( `#chapter` ) . The `#biblepage` page contains the collapsible listview and the `#chapter` page has to load the corresponding data.

Html code:

```
<!-- Home Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="biblepage" data-transition="flip">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

         <div id="collapse_list"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Chapter Page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="chapter">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
                <h1></h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content"></div>

</div>
```

But when I clicked on the `<li>`.The `#chapter` page is not opening(not loading any data).

code:  http://jsfiddle.net/TzX7N/2/

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please post **here** (only) relevant code!

Comment: Check console for error  http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkkbp.png .

Comment: Regardless the problem on JSFiddle, the console is displaying something like this: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #chapter?book=Exod&num=1`

Comment: So many errors, you didnt see this?? where you have looked for errors??

Comment: sometimes i'm getting this error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #chapter?book=Exod&num=1 
i'm using firebug

Answer (score 0):

Your `pagebeforechange` listener is wrong. First, `toPage` is not in the first parameter of the function (which is the event itself), but in the second parameter and second, your regex expression is testing agains `$chapter` instead of `#chapter`. It should be something like:

```
 // Listen for pagebeforechange event
 $(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function (event, data) {
     // only handle changePage() when loading a page by URL.
     if (typeof data.toPage === "string") {
         // Handle URLs that requests chapter page
         var url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage),
             regex = /^#chapter/;
         if (url.hash.search(regex) !== -1) {
             showChapter(url, data.options);
             // tell changePage() we've handled this 
             //e.preventDefault();
         }
     }
 });
```

A demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9zQxM/), notice that the Ajax calls are not working.

Comment: @Lucky Where is not loading? The data will not being loaded in JSFiddle because it uses *Ajax*...

Comment: @Lucky Where are you testing? On my demo, `loadBook` is being reached

Comment: yes but when i'm trying before click on the <li> its loading the book. I'm trying to click load the data after i clicked on <li>

Comment: @Lucky What error do you see in your console? It sounds like a different issue

Comment: @Lucky Like I said, that is a different issue, probably related with Ajax, try to debug that call

Comment: not working getting no such file or directory but i mentioned correct path

Comment: Getting this error "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #chapter?book=Gen&num=1"